# c++ create an object with constructor or wothout?

Tags: c++

I am new to c++.
I have seen some example of classes.
I have difficulty to understand when I have to call the costuctor (whith ()) when I create an object and when I don't have to create it with the consructor.

Comment: Objects are always created with a constructor

Comment: Show some code about creating object with or without constructor.

Comment: Using parentheses just makes the "call" more explicit, but a constructor is always called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor is always invoked when creating a C++ object (of class type).   You can't change that.

Assuming you have a default constructor (one that accepts no arguments between the `()`) then it will be invoked with something as simple as

```
  YourClass x;
```

It is actually a VERY bad idea to use `()` to create an object in this case, since

```
  YourClass thing();
```

The compiler interprets this as a declaration of a function named `thing()`, which accepts no arguments, and returns a value of type `YourClass`.    That will typically cause compilation errors if `thing` is used like a normal object instance.

Comment: As I've recently learned, this is not what Scott Meyers dubbed the most vexing parse.

Comment: What Meyers dubbed as the most vexing parse was in the context of templates.     However, the same problem occurs even outside of templates.   Anyway, I'll remove the reference to vexing parse, as debate of terminology doesn't add anything for the OP.

Comment: @Peter- what about consructor which supposed to get params?

Comment: There is no way to invoke such a constructor without providing parameters between `()`.   For example  `YourClass something(2,3);` to invoke a constructor that accepts two arguments of type `int`.   The compiler will complain bitterly if you get this wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If an object is created, one of its constructors is always called.

```
Foo x;
Foo x{};
```

All of the above statements will do the same, create a `Foo` object using the **default constructor**. Notice that `Foo x();` is not valid in this context, see Peter's answere for an explanation why.

If you have to pass arguments to a constructor or if you have to use *new*, you always have to use brackets:

```
Foo y(42, true);
Foo y{21, false};
Foo* y = new Foo();
Foo* y = new Foo(2, false);
```

Comment: The second case `Foo x()` does NOT create a `Foo`.   It is an example of the most vexing parse.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor always called when you create a object, it can calling implicitly.

```
class SomeClass
{
    SomeClass() {}
};

SomeClass myObject; // in fact it a: SomeClass myObject = SomeClass();
```

Comment: You will find that `SomeClass myObject = SomeClass()` will fail to compile if `SomeClass` does not have an accessible copy constructor.  `SomeClass myObject` will not fail in that circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an Object, you always call a constructor. Either you use round brackets or (with the new Standard) you can use curly brackets. If you want to call a constructor without arguments you can omit the brackets alltogether, but you will still call a constructor.

The only possibility to not call a constructor is if you use pointers, because a pointer only holds a memory address of an object. To actually create an object you need to use `new` (calling a constructor again), but this can be done later or skipped at all, if there is already an object you want to point to.
For builtin types you can also skip the "constructor", which leads to unitialized variables.

If the constructor you call is one you defined yourself or if it is implicitly defined by the compiler is another question though...

Comment: You'll get an error when you "just allocate memory" and try to assign it to an object pointer. That paragraph is just confusing to the uninitiated.

Comment: Is it clearer this way?

Comment: Not really. A paragraph about how to bypass the invariant guaranteed by the language, and mostly with hand-waving, is not constructive in this case IMHO.

Comment: It is not about bypassing any guarantee. If you write `Object* ptr;` no constructor of Object is called, it is just a pointer that might be linked to an object later. A constructor is only called when writing `ptr = new Object();`